# Acer Chromebook C710-B842 hardware write-protect screw

Tags: chromebook

Where is the hardware write-protect screw on this laptop Acer Chromebook C710-B842 ?

Comment: No hardware manual for it at Acer Support https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/4591?b=1 so you may need to contact them directly at https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support

Answer (score 0):

The write protect for the C710 is not a screw. It is a section of the motherboard that needs to be shorted to remove write protection. 
Refer to this picture:

[image]

Under the black tab is two metal contacts. They must be joined together with either solder or a conductive material. Please be **extremely** careful not to short anything else.

This video shows more in detail of how to short it and also maybe what you are trying to achieve:
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtBTjKmkmJ4)